# Require at least one of two fields using vee-validate on VueJS 2.0

Tags: validation, vuejs2

I am using [vee-validate](http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/) and I have two fields; one for **Home Phone** and one for **Cell Phone**. I don't need to make both *'required'* for the rules, but what I need is at least one of these required.

So, my question, is it possible to set up a rule that checks both fields for input in at least one of them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, didn't take long, but I have this working. It just took a bit of digging, so posting my answer so it can help others.

First, my input fields are `homephone` and `cellphone` and at least one of them is required.

This is achievable using the computed properties in Vue with the following:

```js
computed: {
    isHomePhoneRequired() {
        if(this.cellphone === '')
            return true; // homephone is required
        return false;
    },
    isCellPhoneRequired() {
        // check if homephone is empty
        if(this.homephone === '')
            return true; // cellphone is required
        return false;
    }
}
```

and my HTML looks like the following:

```html
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('homephone') }">
    <div class="label">Home Phone<i class="fa fa-asterisk required" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div ><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="homephone" v-validate ="{ rules: { required: this.isHomePhoneRequired} }" data-vv-name="homephone" data-vv-as="Home Phone" /></div>
    <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has('homephone')">{{ errors.first('homephone') }}</p>
</div>
<div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('cellphone') }">
    <div class="label">Cell Phone<i class="fa fa-asterisk required" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <div ><input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="cellphone" v-validate ="{ rules: { required: this.isCellPhoneRequired} }" data-vv-name="cellphone" data-vv-as="Cell Phone" /></div>
    <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has('cellphone')">{{ errors.first('cellphone') }}</p>
</div>
```

Notice that v-validate now gets an object passed containing the type (`rules`), the validation to use (`required`), and the computed property (`isHomePhoneRequired`).

Comment: I think you could do this with a custom validation rule  - http://vee-validate.logaretm.com/rules.html#custom-rules

Answer (score 4):

I think using computed is not necessary, we can simply make it happen in HTML itself by checking condition on validating rules for another input model as below:

```
        <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('homephone') }">
            <div class="label">Home Phone<i class="fa fa-asterisk required" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div ><input type="text" v-validate ="{ rules: { required: cellphone?false:true} }" class="form-control" v-model="homephone" data-vv-name="homephone" data-vv-as="Home Phone" /></div>
            <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has('homephone')">{{ errors.first('homephone') }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" :class="{'has-error': errors.has('cellphone') }">
            <div class="label">Cell Phone<i class="fa fa-asterisk required" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            <div ><input type="text" v-validate ="{ rules: { required: homephone?false:true} }" class="form-control" v-model="cellphone" data-vv-name="cellphone" data-vv-as="Cell Phone" /></div>
            <p class="text-danger" v-if="errors.has('cellphone')">{{ errors.first('cellphone') }}</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Vee-Validate `ValidationProvider` by binding `rules`

`homePhone` will be required if `cellPhone` is null or empty string

```
<ValidationProvider
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  vid="homePhone"
  :rules="{
    required: !cellPhone || cellPhone.length === 0,
  }"
  name="Home Phone"
>
```

And same with `cellPhone`

```
<ValidationProvider
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  vid="cellPhone"
  :rules="{
    required: !homePhone || homePhone.length === 0,
  }"
  name="Cell Phone"
>
```